# Given distances between n points, how to draw a map from those relationships

Tags: math, language-agnostic, puzzle

I came across an interesting question in my textbook, but not further answer or details were supplied :(

Given some points, A, B, C etc

and some distance relationships between those points:

```
A -> B = 23
A -> C = 45

B -> A = 23
B -> C = 78

C -> A = 45
C -> B = 78
```

So this distance between C and A is 45 units, A and B is 23 units etc

How to draw a map or some sort of representation? Is it just a case of constraining against those rules until you converge?

Comment: In 2D or 3D? This problem can be solved by map distance to force, and this problem will become a multi-particle dynamics problem. You may get some inspiration from [Ubigraph](http://ubietylab.net/ubigraph/content/Demos/index.html), it's a very cool visualizing tool.

Comment: Do you have *all* distances? That is, if you're given 5 points, will you be given all 10 distances?

Comment: @lnafziger, 5! = 120, and the number of distances is n(n-1)/2, not n!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is only 3 points, it is a simple triangle, and you know the distances of the three sides from the table:  23, 45, and 78 "units".

So you can plot any two of the points as a straight line, then do a little bit of math to determine the angle to the third point (and you already know the distance):

```
// a, b, and c are the distances, C is the angle.
c² = b² + a² - 2ba cosC
```

Solve that and you have the angle across point C so you can plot the third point.

**Edit (I originally missed that this was for N points since it was only in the subject):**.

If you don't have **all** of the distances, then you will have to find three that do have all three legs defined to use as a starting point and plot those.  After that, find another point that has distances defined to two of your existing points and calculate your new triangle with those three points and plot that one.  Repeat this until you run out of points.

Comment: If you have the same information, then you can just pick three points and figure them out like above.  Then take two of your already plotted points and one new point and repeat.  Do this until all 20 points have been plotted.

Comment: Good luck drawing a triangle with sides 78,45,23.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Good point, those numbers aren't valid, however the method is....

Answer (score 0):

I think [multidimensional scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling) is what you want. For example, given distances between U.S. cities, you'll get something like this:

[image]

There may not be a way to perfectly satisfy your constraints in 2- or 3-D, but this will minimize the cost function.